# RavenDB polymorphic Index

Tags: c#, database, ravendb

I'm working with RavenDB, and I'm trying to do something. I have a base type, Principal, from which two classes are derived: User and ApplicationInstance. In my application, instances of User and ApplicationInstance must be created and stored frequently. The thing is, though, that I need to also be able to query all of the Principal objects stored in the database at once, determine whether a given Principal is a User or an ApplicationInstance, and then query for the entire User or ApplicationInstance object.

How can I do this?

Comment: The official doc on the subject - [Indexing polymorphic data](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/all/indexes/indexing-polymorphic-data)

Answer (score 2):

You can define a [Multi Map Index](http://ayende.com/blog/89089/ravendb-multi-maps-reduce-indexes) that uses as source both the `User` and `ApplicationInstance` collections.

If you define your index using C# code (by implementing `AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask<>`), you'll have to call `AddMap` twice to achieve that (as illustrated in the blog post link above)

If you define the index using Raven Studio, simply click the *Add Map* button and you'll get a new text area which allows you to define an additional Map.

Note, however, that the output structure of both maps must have the same properties (pretty much as you would do with UNION in SQL).

Comment: Multimap is the way to go here. You can even use transform results to load the principle into a property on the result document to keep more stuff on the server.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do? If the end result is to query all Principals, then load the entire User or AppInstance, why not just go straight for querying all Users or all AppInstances?

Raven won't store base classes; it will only store the most derived type (User or AppInstance, in your case). So you'll have a collection of Users and a collection of AppInstances.

If you really need to query both at once, you can use [Multi Map indexes](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/client-api/querying/polymorphism). You can also change the entity name and store both in a single Principal collection.

But it's difficult to recommend a solution without knowing what you're trying to do. **Explain what you're trying to do and we'll tell you the proper way to get there.**

Comment: Well, I'm trying to manage access to resources. Many of the documents stored in the database contain a sort of ACL that corresponds Principal objects (their Ids) and the permissions (e.g. read, write, delete, change ownership) possessed by said principals. I was trying to, given the Id of the Principal in the ACL, query for either the general principal object or the specific AppInstance or User. Here's what I mean:      
`Principal p = session.Load<Principal>(id);   
if (p is AppInstance) { ... }   
elseif (p is User) { ... }`   

Or do I just have the wrong idea?

Comment: What happens when you .Load<Principal>(id)? What do you get back? I'd expect Raven to give you back the right object, regardless of what you sent in as the type parameter.